# Airbnb JS StyleGuide & history.push don't combine

Tags: reactjs, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm writing a React app, namely a navbar.
I have a logo and navItems there.
Logo display and color of the navbar background are conditional.
Added Aibnb guide to esLint, now my navbar code looks like this:

```
class Toolbar extends Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        this.props.history.push('/');
    }

    render() {
        const { color, showLogo } = this.props;
        return (
            <header
                style={{
                    backgroundColor: color,
                }}
                className={classes.Toolbar}
            >
                <Logo click={this.handleClick} show={showLogo} />
                <NavItems />
            </header>
        );
    }
}

Toolbar.propTypes = {
    color: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    showLogo: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default withRouter(Toolbar);
```

and I get the following eslint errors:

[image: eslint errors]

(line 11) is

```
this.props.history.push('/');
```

How do I transform this method to make the code compile and work without errors?

(Tried to rewrite it in as a destructing props assignment, got an error like cannot get 'push' of undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should update

```
Toolbar.propTypes = {
color: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
showLogo: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
history:PropTypes.node
};
```

or

```
const {history} = this.props
```

**Update**

`history:PropTypes.shape({push:PropTypes.func})`

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `history` *PropType* will help you get rid of the error:

```
Toolbar.propTypes = {
  color: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  showLogo: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  history: PropTypes.shape({
    push: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
};
```